# How to store data in different lists

Tags: python-3.x

I have 3 lists that related to each, I would like to use python to put them into 3 different lists or dictionary, or whatever it works. The data in the datelist is kind of primary key

```
datelist = [1, 2, 2, 11, 11, 11, 11]
inlist = [61345098075, 61453498075, 34353, 23421, 23421, 23421, 23421]
outlist = [61345816236, 61434636236, 43532, 63345816236, 34276816236, 34566816236, 84876816236]
```

The output I would like to have is like below

```
inlist_1 = [61345098075]
outlist_1 = [61345816236]
inlist_2 = [61453498075, 34353]
outlist_2 = [61434636236, 43532]
inlist_11 = [23421, 23421, 23421, 23421]
outlist_11 = [63345816236, 34276816236, 34566816236, 84876816236]
```

The 1, 2, 11 in the datelist I would like to save them as variable as well for future use.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If as you state, the key values are the date items, you should make dictionaries using that.  And it seems you want 2 dictionaries.  The other alternative to the below is to store tuples of the in/out in the same dictionary.

```
In [12]: from collections import defaultdict                                    

In [13]: %paste                                                                 
datelist = [1, 2, 2, 11, 11, 11, 11]
inlist = [61345098075, 61453498075, 34353, 23421, 23421, 23421, 23421]
outlist = [61345816236, 61434636236, 43532, 63345816236, 34276816236, 34566816236, 84876816236]

## -- End pasted text --

In [14]: in_dict=defaultdict(list)                                              

In [15]: out_dict=defaultdict(list)                                             

In [16]: for date, i, j in zip(datelist, inlist, outlist): 
    ...:     in_dict[date].append(i) 
    ...:     out_dict[date].append(j) 
    ...:                                                                        

In [17]: in_dict.get(2)                                                         
Out[17]: [61453498075, 34353]

In [18]: out_dict.get(11)                                                       
Out[18]: [63345816236, 34276816236, 34566816236, 84876816236]

In [19]:
```